# Django -- how to use templatetags filter with multiple arguments

Tags: python, django, filter, django-templates, tags

I have a few values that I would like to pass into a filter and get a URL out of it.

In my template I have:

```
{% if names %}
  {% for name in names %}
    <a href='{{name|slugify|add_args:"custid=name.id, sortid=2"}}'>{{name}}</a>
    {%if not forloop.last %} | {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

In my templatetags I have:

```
@register.filter
def add_args(value, args):
    argz = value.strip() + '-' + 'ARGS'
    arglist = args.split(',')
    for arg in arglist:
        keyval = arg.split('=')
        argz.join(keyval[0] + 'ZZ' + keyval[1])
        argz.join('QQ')

    return argz
```

The output URL should look like:

```
http://foo.org/john-smith-ARGScustidZZ11QQsortidZZ2
```

Where ARGS is the start of the arguments, ZZ is '=' and QQ is an '&' equivalent.

First of all: This would work, but I get the custid=name.id coming in the add_args(), where I want to have custid=11 to come in. How pass in the id as an id and not text.

Also, is there a way to just send in an array of key=>value like in PHP.
In PHP I would build an array, let say:

```
arglist = array('custid' => $nameid, 'sortid' => $sortid );
```

Then I would pass the arglist as an argument to `add_args()` and in `add_args()` I would do

```
foreach( arglist as $key => $value)
  $argstr .= $key . 'ZZ' . $value . 'QQ'.
```

Does anyone have a better way of making this work?

Note: if I have to pass all arguments as a string and split them up in the filter I don't mind. I just don't know how to pass the name.id as its value ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This "smart" stuff logic should not be in the template.
Build your end-of-urls in your view and then pass them to template:

```
def the_view(request):
  url_stuff = "custid=%s, sortid, ...." % (name.id, 2 ...)

  return render_to_response('template.html',
    {'url_stuff':url_stuff,},
    context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

In template.html:

```
 ....

    <a href='{{url_stuff}}'>{{name}}</a>

 ....
```

If you need a url for a whole bunch of objects consider using [get_absolute_url](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) on the model.

Comment: things like sort id are outside the object model. So, I guess they have to be passed in. And if I have to pass args here and there, I might just pass it to the filter. all I am trying to do is to do http://foo.com/some-slugy-stuff-ArgsID22Sort2/. This way, every link knows what do load and if you copy and paste and email to friends they can see exactly what you want them to see. Trust me, I know how to do it the Django way. I guess noone knows or bothered to lean how to pass in multiple args to a filter. Thanks for your replay though!

Comment: Why use args to complicated tags instead of  using named urls?

Comment: +1 for recommending `get_absolute_url`. Here's a good [blog post](http://www.achanceofbrainshowers.com/blog/tech/2010/11/29/djangos_permalink_decorator/) about the `permalink` decorator to use with it, and how it can be very cool.

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass `name.id` to your filter. Filter arguments can be asingle value or a single literal. Python/Django doesn't attempt any "smart" variable replacement like PHP.

I suggest you to create a tag for this task:

```
<a href='{% add_args "custid" name.id "sortid" "2" %}{{name|slugify}}{% end_add_args %}'>{{name}}</a>
```

This way you can know which argument is a literal value and which should be taken fron context etc... Docs are quite clear about this, take a look at the [example](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag).

Also if this `name` is any way related to a model, say we want to get to the permalink, adding a method that returns the URL with the proper arguments might be the tidiest solution.

Overall, I would refrain putting too much logic into templates. Django is not PHP.

Comment: What I want to achieve by this line (<a href='{{name|slugify|add_args:"custid=name.id, sortid=2"}}'>{{name}}</a>) is: take the first name & last name, sluify them. So we have "john-smith". Then pass that as the value to add_args. Then pass the value of custid and sortid as arguments to add_args. Then have add_args return a text like "john-smith-argscustidzz1qqsortidzz2".

Now could you kindly translate the line you just provide, to see if the output will match what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by `translate`? It is already django-template.

Comment: just don't know what your line will do and in what order. I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work unless someone implements it. That is basically the idea for a custom template tag. I didn't give an implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `argz.join` a couple times and never assigning the results to anything: maybe you're operating under the misconception that the `join` method of a string has some mysterious side effect, but it doesn't -- it just returns a new string, and if you don't do anything with that new string, *poof*, it's gone. Is that at least part of your problem...?

Comment: good catch! I typed everything in ... missed the assignment. Also new to python. Try to get away from PHP, but I find Django's learning curve very very steep. It is a moving target as APIs are constantly changing and being deprecated and phased out.

Comment: PHP is not Django. You cannot compare the two. First you learn python. Then you learn Django. Why bring PHP-like mentality into Django web framework?

Comment: PHP is used to explain the expected behavior. So, I know what I want, I know how it is done in PHP, now trying to find out how I can leave PHP behind and move to PyDj.